# How to disable url & bottom bar on iphone

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, iphone

I am making an web app in html, css and js nad would like to hide the address bar and the bottom bar in the web browser on iPhone.

I've had no luck so far and have tried with following:

```
   /mobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && setTimeout(function () {
   window.scrollTo(0, 1);
   }, 1000);
```

And used the meta tags:

```
name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"
name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"
```

Comment: Hope you can help me, thank you.

Comment: I believe you first need to add the website to your homepage. When you open the website then from your homescreen it should act correctly

Answer (score 1):

In the native Safari browser on IOS, there is no way to disable the menu and address bar. This would normally disappear when the user is scrolling. If you make a bookmark on the home screen by pressing the [share button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ews88.png). The web app will appear without the address bar and menu bar. Hope this helped! -Todd

Comment: Thank you, it did. I guess I would have to make a one page with #href's and it will work out :)